# Rails - working with scaffolding, error linking to the new resource that was made

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning Ruby on Rails and i did this scaffolding command:

```
rails g scaffold Alex
```

and it ran and created all the resources for me.  So I tried to make a link from my index page to the alex page like this:

```
<%= link_to "Alex Link", alex_path(@alex) %>
```

(I am still not sure what that @alex part is, but it was in the other examples so I tried to have that there)

and in my routes.rb this code was created:

```
  resources :alexes

  get "home/index"
```

and when I tried to load the link, it gave me this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"alexes"}
```

Just in case, here is the output from `rake routes`:

```
    alexes GET    /alexes(.:format)          alexes#index
           POST   /alexes(.:format)          alexes#create
  new_alex GET    /alexes/new(.:format)      alexes#new
 edit_alex GET    /alexes/:id/edit(.:format) alexes#edit
      alex GET    /alexes/:id(.:format)      alexes#show
           PUT    /alexes/:id(.:format)      alexes#update
           DELETE /alexes/:id(.:format)      alexes#destroy
home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)      home#index
      root        /                          home#index
      test POST   /test(.:format)            tests#create
  new_test GET    /test/new(.:format)        tests#new
 edit_test GET    /test/edit(.:format)       tests#edit
           GET    /test(.:format)            tests#show
           PUT    /test(.:format)            tests#update
           DELETE /test(.:format)            tests#destroy
```

What is wrong with the way that I made the link and how can I make it hit the controller before it goes to the view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alex_path` is for showing a *specific* `Alex` object. To use it, `@alex` needs to be an instance of an `Alex` object loaded by your controller.

You say you want to link to the "Alex page", which makes me think you want the listing of *all* `Alex` objects, or the `index` action of your `AlexController`. If this is the case, you should use `alexes_path` instead of `alex_path(@alex)`.

If you actually do want to link to a single specific `Alex`, you'll need to load an instance from the database:

```
def my_action
  # make a specific Alex object available to the view
  @alex = Alex.find(...)
end
```

---

As an aside, you also ask:

> how can I make it hit the controller before it goes to the view?

Your controller will *always* be hit before the views are rendered. It is impossible for a view to be rendered without an action being invoked.

Comment: thanks! That worked. So the alexes_path would get all matching instances and alex_path would require some id to get a specific one?  Also, after the link rendered, and I clicked it, I got this error on the next page: Could not find table 'alexes'   ...which is because I don't have such a table.  Should I not have specified something if I didn't want the db calls?

Comment: If you don't want to use a database table to store `Alex` objects, you shouldn't have used scaffolding. Scaffolding builds a controller, views and a model to support an entire RESTful resource. You'll need to open `alexes_controller.rb` and remove most of the code. Alternatively, you'll need to run your migration to create the table in question.